# Cannot figure out how to properly configure eclipse formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, whitespace, formatter

I am havinging a problem with eclipses formatter that i cannot seem to figure out.

If i have a line of code with comments that is over 80 characters, like:

```
Something something = new Something(somethingElse) // some comments here about the code.
```

then the first time i run the formatter, it will set it up correctly, like:

```
Something something = new Something(somethingElse) // some comments here
                                                   // about the code.
```

However, if i then run the formatter again later, it will change it to:

```
Something something = new Something(somethingElse) // some comments here
// about the code.
```

I feel like there should be something obvious here that i am missing, but i have looked through all the formatter settings that i could find and have yet to find a way to prevent this behaivor. Does anyone have any insight to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second time the formatter is run, it doesn't understand that `// about the code` is part of the comment on the line above, and it decides that line needs to be flush with the code. Looking through the settings, I don't see an obvious way around it. I'd suggest either only putting short comments on the end of lines and/or putting the comments on the line above. (Or, not using the formatter, which is usually my preference.)

```
// some comments here about the code. If it's long enough it'll wrap
// like this.
Something something = new Something(somethingElse) // Short note
```